# Grade average display (Average of the grades not displaying)

Tags: java

making a program that asks how many grades you will average, then you enter grades, it will add and average them. I am not getting any errors, but the class average will not display correctly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExerciseFour
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        Scanner dylan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int total;
        int gradeCounter;
        int grade;      
        int average;    
        int numberofGrades;

        System.out.println("How many grades do you want to average?");
        numberofGrades = dylan.nextInt();



        total = 0;
        gradeCounter = 1;

        while ( gradeCounter <= numberofGrades )
        {
            System.out.println("Enter grade");
            grade = dylan.nextInt();
            total = total + grade;
            gradeCounter = gradeCounter +1;
        }


        average = total / numberofGrades;
        System.out.printf("The average is ", average );


    }

}
```

First it asks how many to enter, I pressed 4. I enter 4, 4, 4, 4, and it came up with 
"The average is "
I want it to display the average of the grades, help? :D

Comment: Unless you're tokenizing your string, `printf` doesn't take an arbitrary number of arguments. Use string concatenation instead. `String average = "average: " + total/numberofGrades;`

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
System.out.printf("The average is ", average);
```

To

```
System.out.printf("The average is %lf", average);
```

Or

```
System.out.println("The average is " + average);
```

Also note that you're doing `int` calculations. `average` should be `double` and you should cast one side:

```
average = (double)total / numberofGrades;
```

Comment: Thanks :) Also, do you know how I would allow it to display a decimal? I think it has something to do with float values but I'm unsure

Answer (score 0):

`printf` is great for formatting, so if you want to format your number to two decimal places, you can use this approach:

```
System.out.printf("The average is %.2f", average );
```

The `%.2f` says, "Format this float to two decimal places." ([Further documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html))

However, if you want this to work with your code, you must change your declaration of `average` to be a `float`.

```
float average;
```

Also note that both the integers you are dividing to get your average are `ints`, so you will need to cast this calculation to a `float`:

```
average = (float) total / numberofGrades;
```

Comment: Okay, I have it producing a number with two decimals. But, I averaged 2 numbers, 5 and 2, and the result was 3. It's rounding down it seems, as 5 + 2 / 2 = 3.5

EDIT: Fixed it by changing total to a float value :)

Comment: See my edit. You will need to cast that line to a float, since you are dividing an `int` by an `int`. This results in an `int` that is only cast to a `float` after it is assigned to `average`, resulting in the integer truncation you are seeing. You need to cast it to a float *before* it is assigned. Technically, this approach just casts `total` to a float, which is sufficient, since it will remain a `float` even after it is divided by an `int`.